# How to put text field instead of %{...} in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have the next string:

```
'The weather is too %{condition} today.'
```

Now I want to paste instead of `%{condition}` a text field, so it will look like:

```
The weather is too __text_field__ today.
```

I've tried:

```
if text.include? "%{"
    =text_field_tag(:q, nil, class: "")
```

but it pastes after the whole sentence. How can I put/replace `%{}` with my text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Kernel#sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)

```
= sprintf('The weather is too %s today.', 
   text_field_tag(:q, nil, class: "")).html_safe
```

or [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub)

```
= 'The weather is too %{condition} today.'.
  gsub(/%{(\w*)}/, text_field_tag(:q, nil, class: "")).html_safe
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
("The weather is too %{condition} today." % { condition: text_field_tag(:q, nil, class: "") }).html_safe
```

Answer (score 2):

Snippets by @max are good enough, but answering the exact question stated, it would be:

```
= text % {condition: text_field_tag(:q, nil, class: "")).html_safe}
```